# SQLAlchemy ? operator on JSONB key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple table with a JSONB column. In that field I have a key: `key` and the value of the `key` can be either a list with `["val1", "val2"]` or single string `"val2"`.

I got a raw SQL query that retrieves when a value in `key` is `"val2"`:

```
SELECT t.c FROM t WHERE t.c->'key' ? "val2"
```

However, I am struggling to replicate this in SQLAlchemy query:

I have a `session`

```
query = session.query(t).filter(t.c.has_key('val2'))
```

which results in

`SELECT t.c FROM t WHERE t.c ? 'val2'` but I want `?` operator on `->`.

The only way to get `->` (as far as I could find) is by using `filter(t.c['key2'])`. However, then I can't perform `has_key()` I get:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'JSONElement' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'has_key'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Though perhaps not optimal, you can work around this with `filter(t.c['key2'].op('?')('val2'))`, or update your SQLAlchemy. The newer versions work correctly in this case.

Comment: Or: `filter(t.c['key'].has_key('val2'))`

Comment: @IljaEverilä Nice one, can you please add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older versions of SQLAlchemy's `JSONB` columns produce `JSONElement` objects on item access that seem to lack certain json comparator methods, such as `has_key()`. The `JSONB` type was introduced in version 1.0 and backported to 0.9.7, but I think [this was fixed in 1.1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_11.html#change-955064818187d78a11ba0c613973c45a). In the mean time if you are unable to upgrade your SQLAlchemy, you can work around this using the [generic `op()` operator function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.op):

```
query = session.query(t).\
    filter(t.c['key2'].op('?')('val2'))
```

and when you've finally managed to upgrade you can just

```
filter(t.c['key2'].has_key('val2'))
```

as expected.

Comment: Good spot re vrsion, was using 1.0.17. But it's good to know about `.op()`.